# How to create a list out of a text string in another cell?

Tags: excel, list

I need to know how i can use a string in a cell like:     `{"Alpha";"Beta";"Gamma";"Delta"}`
in an index-function in another cell.

If i write `=INDEX({"Alpha";"Beta";"Gamma";"Delta"};2)` it correctly shows Beta in the cell.

If i fill the cell A1 with

`{"Alpha";"Beta";"Gamma";"Delta"}`

or

`={"Alpha";"Beta";"Gamma";"Delta"}`

and fill another cell with

`=INDEX(A1;2)`

or

`=INDEX(INDIRECT(A1);2)`

it throws a reference-error. Is this just a formatting issue or not possible in excel?

Comment: What do you actually want to have in the referenced cell? A semi-colon (or other) delimited list? So, for example, "Alpha;Beta;Gamma;Delta"?

Comment: Yes, actually i need to have some customer numbers in there, preferably separated by commas, but that doesn't matter much, semicolons or anything else would be ok, too. Example: "345781,346879,342722"

Comment: Replied. Apologies - just revised by solution which you may not have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the list is comma-separated, e.g. "Alpha,Beta,Gamma,Delta", this:

`TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))-1)+1,LEN(A1)))`

will generate the array {"Alpha";"Beta";"Gamma";"Delta"} which can then be passed to some function for processing:

Hence you could use:

`=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))))-1)+1,LEN(A1))),n)`

where *n* is some index of your choosing. For example, with *n*=2, the above would return "Beta" for the example string given.

However, given that you appear to wish to pass this array to a simple INDEX construction, it is probably preferable to use instead:

`=MID(A1,FIND("ζ",SUBSTITUTE(","&A1&",",",","ζ",n)),MMULT(FIND("ζ",SUBSTITUTE(","&A1&",",",","ζ",n+{0,1})),{-1;1})-1)`

where, again, the two instances of *n* should be replaced with your choice of index.

Regards

Comment: Thanks very much! I don't exactly understand why, but it works as intended. I had to convert it to the german function-names and syntax, so for anyone else who needs this: `=INDEX(GLÄTTEN(TEIL(WECHSELN(A1;",";WIEDERHOLEN(" ";LÄNGE(A1)));LÄNGE(A1)*(ZEILE(INDEX(A:A;1):INDEX(A:A;1+LÄNGE(A1)-LÄNGE(WECHSELN(A1;",";""))))-1)+1;LÄNGE(A1)));n)`

Comment: You're welcome. Like I said, though, the second formula is probably preferable in terms of efficiency. Set-ups with TRIM/SUBSTITUTE/REPT can be surprisingly resource-heavy. However, the first construction is certainly useful from a theoretical point of view, and is more flexible in the sense that the array generated can be passed to any function of choosing.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd works, too and is also better understandable. I'll use the return-value for a vlookup, so both versions are working. I hadn't even thought about just using the mid-function. Now that i see it, i think i can short it down even further since all my values have a fixed length of 6 numbers. Thx for the help and as previously done, here is the german version for those that might need it: `=TEIL(A1;FINDEN("ζ";WECHSELN(","&A1&",";",";"ζ";n));MMULT(FINDEN("ζ";WECHSELN(","&A1&",";",";"ζ";n+{0.1}));{-1;1})-1)`